# For loop to print out squares of numbers

Tags: php

I'm attempting to create a for loop to print out the square of every number between 1-100.

```
<?php

for ($count = 1; $count < 100; $count++){
  $squared = $count * $count;
  print("$count squared is $squared");
}

?>
```

What im getting is this.

"1 squared is 12 squared is 43 squared is 94 squared is 165 squared is 256" etc...
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: You are all lifesavers and I am dumb, long live Stack Overflow.

Comment: It IS working the way you specify. If formatting the answer is what you want you'll need to add a `<br/>` or something to the end of the `print()` statement to make it legible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add a newline at the end of your print `\n` should do it

```
<?php

for ($count = 1; $count < 100; $count++){
  $squared = $count * $count;
  print("$count squared is $squared \n");
}

?>
```

If you output this in an html page, a `<br>` is perhaps the way to go!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a line break thus:

```
<?php

for ($count = 1; $count < 100; $count++){
  $squared = $count * $count;
  print("$count squared is $squared\n");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pow($base,$exponent) function;

```
<?php

for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++) echo $i.' squared is '.pow($i,2).'<br />';

?>
```

Comment: Yeah I would, but this is for an assignment and I think the main point was the concept of thinking in loops more than just using a function.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you want!?

Comment: @Corjava this is a loop. Just a one-liner loop without brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Or a different solution

```
<?php
for ($count = 1; $count < 1000; $count++){
  $squared = $count * $count;
  print("$count  squared is $squared <br>");
}
?>
```